# adb devices not visisble within windows subsystem(WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, adb

When I run `adb devices` from poweshell of windows I see list of atached devices.
But when I run `adb devices` from within windows subsystem(ubuntu 18.04) I see nothing. How can I fix it?
I need to run scripts from ubuntu to my android devices. How do I do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62145379 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/27245597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant "subsystem" instead of "file system"  in the title right?

Well officially you can't. Atleast not untill `wsl --mount` functionality is released, but there's a trick(hack rather) which works.

ADB is actually two components, a daemon that does the device communication and a client that talks to the daemon over a local network socket. So first install the exact same version of ADB in both Windows and WSL, then start/restart the ADB daemon in Windows by running :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Then in ADB in WSL it should automatically use the already running daemon and be able to talk to your devices normally.
Now run in WSL

`adb devices`

**NOTE**: You must have the same version of ADB on Windows and WSL. If you have installed ADB on WSL via commandline. Note down its version with `adb version` and then coming back to windows to do the same, if you find the version on windows is different then you may have to download the appropiate version of `platform_tools` . You may have to do bit of trial and error as android don't explicitly mention on their downloads page which version of `adb` ships with which version of `platofrm_tools`.

Comment: Works for me with Galaxy A50.

Comment: You can see all platform tools and their included adb versions here: https://github.com/awake558/adb-win/blob/master/SDK_Platform-Tools_for_Windows/readme.md